# How to tell that AVAudioPlayer has finished playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, avaudioplayer

I'm developing an app that plays sounds using `AVAudioPlayer`, and I want to know when a sound has finished playing. I want to change an image when the sound stops playing

Here's the code I use to create the player:

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LOLManFace1"  withExtension:@"mp3"];
NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid.");
NSError* error = nil;
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&url];error;

if(!self.player)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}
```

And here's the code I use to play the sound:

```
[self.player play];
```

How can I tell that playback has finished?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Look at the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol which has a method to tell the delegate when audio playback has finished among other things, specifically what you are looking for is `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`, here is a [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008068)

Hope it helps

Daniel

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, I call [self audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:self.player successfully:YES] on my button action, but inside an if statement cause I want to know if the sound ends, but an error jumps how can i put this on a if to be able to change the image?

Comment: You are not using this correctly, refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html to see the workflow of protocols and delegates

Answer (score 3):

Long time ago and I am pretty sure you figured out at one point. If someone reads this post:

1) Your class should implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate)

One of the delegate methods is:

```
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:
```

2) Set delegate:

```
self.player.delegate = self
```