# Audio play button - Start, Stop

Tags: swift, button, audio, playback

I am new to swift, thanks in advance for your help. I am designing audio play button. Below is the code. The button will show "start" and "stop". Once clicking "start", the button displays "stop" during audio playing, which is right. The problem is that after finishing the whole audio file playing, the following code can't automatically flip button display from "stop" back to "start". It is stuck at "stop" before pressing twice back to "start".

```
@IBAction func didTapButton() {
    if let player = player, player.isPlaying {
        // Stop playback
        button.setTitle("start", for: .normal)
        player.stop()
    }
    else {
        // set up player, and play
        button.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)
        let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "go", ofType: "mp3")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            guard let urlString = urlString else {
                return
            }
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString))
            guard let player = player else {
                return
            }
            player.play()
        }
        catch {
            print("something went wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate should help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627872/2942751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` and set delegate for the player

```
player.delegate = self
```

then update the button title:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    button.setTitle("start", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.